# How do I make a intensity plot with x, y, and z in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have an x value array named 'age,' a y value array named 'weight' and a z value array named 'calories.' I want to plot x vs y vs intensity. Basically the calorie consumption depending on age and weight.

I can do this in matlab using imagesc, but I need help in Python

```
age = [5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,10....40,40,40,40,40],  
weight = [40,50,55,60,65,80,85,90,95,100....170,190,210,250,300]
calories =[ 500,550,560,600,650,1000,1200,1300,1400,1500...2000,2300,2500,3000,5000]
```

I've tried `plt.pcolormesh` and `plt.imshow` but both imshow doesn't let me put 3 variables as inputs.

I've also tried to create a meshgrid using x,y arrays, but i dont get the right intensity or axes

```py
x=np.unique(age)
y=np.unique(weight)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z=calories.reshape(len(y),len(x))

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

AND

```py
plt.imshow(age,weight,calories)
```

I expected to see an image plot with age on the x axis and weight on the y axis and light to dark color bar

Comment: What is the shape of your x,y,z values?

Answer (score 3):

This are fancy data, but try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mclr

nx = 38; ny = 18

x = np.linspace(0,nx-1,nx)
y = np.linspace(0,ny-1,ny)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
Z =np.sqrt(X*X + Y*Y) # set a fancy Z function

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22,11)) 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, edgecolors='w',cmap="plasma")
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Tx! If it is the accepted answer for you then you might click the "accepted" check box (which is just below the up/down vote signs and gets green when clicked). So everybody knows, that no more answers are needed and that this task is closed.

Answer (score 2):

The plot you use will be dependent on the shape of your data and whether your `calories` array is a function of both `age` and `weight`. If `calories` is 2D, then you should use something like `plt.contourf()`,`plt.imshow()`, or `plt.pcolormesh()`.  You might want to consider a scatter plot like afb mentioned if all your arrays have the same shape.

For example using a subset of your data you can get the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

age = [5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,10,40,40,40,40,40] 
weight = [40,50,55,60,65,80,85,90,95,100,170,190,210,250,300]
calories =[ 500,550,560,600,650,1000,1200,1300,1400,1500,2000,2300,2500,3000,5000]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

sc = plt.scatter(age,weight, s = 200, c=calories, cmap=plt.cm.jet)

cbar = fig.colorbar(sc, orientation='horizontal')    

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You for the help. I've also tried importing my data to pandas dataframe and using seaborn heatmap for the image.  That seemed to work also

Comment: You should know that shows completely different things. Heatmaps show the density of where you have data, not the values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

For `imshow()`, the horizontal and vertical coordinates and the rgb color codes are combined into a single array -- parameter `X` (see description in the documentation https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html). Alternatively, if your dataset does not cover every point in the grid, you might consider a scatter plot, where size and/or color of each marker are proportional to `calories`.